# How to force IP packets over a specific server?

Tags: networking, routes, openstack-neutron

I need to configure hosts to route their network packets in a way that they pass another specific server (in my own network) before they reach their destination.

An example network setup can be seen at the following link which was provided by StackOverflow:

[image]

I have two hosts (Host-1 and Host-2) which communicate with each other over a Gateway/Router in a star network. The specific server (called NetEM-Host) is needed for NetEM manipulation and also connected to the Gateway.

Now, every packet that the two hosts send needs to be first routed over NetEM-Host and only afterwards reach its destination.

How can I configure the network in this way, without altering the Gateway?

(FYI: The Gateway was configured by OpenStack and I cannot SSH on it to change things.)

I was thinking about altering the routing table ("route") of Host-1 and Host-2 but the NetEM-Host would not be the next-hop for the two hosts and thus I cannot define it there, am I correct? Any suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: why not place host-1 and host-2 on two different private networks? Then you can connect netem-host with two ports -- one port in one network and one in another. Then you can configure host-1 and host-2 use netem-host as the next hop in the routing table.